# i want url see below but now see below routing

Tags: codeigniter-3

in www.home.com/monk/visedeals
here Monk is controller and visedeals is passed in monk controller

```
as$any =$this->uri->segment(1); 
by route define this working $route['monk/(:any)'] = 'monk/index/$1';
```

but i wanted as www.home.com/visedeals

i tried also this `$route['(:any)'] = "/monk/index/$1";` it working but others stopped like  www.home.com/admin  or etc

```
public function index()
{
    $any =$this->uri->segment(1);
    $data = $this->monk_model->get_members($any);
```

**error 404 not found  how route the controller as explained above**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: can anyone provide the solutoin

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom route in config/routes.php - for example:

```
$route['visedeals'] = 'monk/index';

Then, www.home.com/visedeals
goes to www.home.com/monk/visedeals
```

Comment: hi ishita . i can do this but not a solution if i have list of 1000 peoples. i already use this .. But i wanted everytime without opening my route file . i can open all the link as you see above my code.